# What are some interesting grading/curving systems you have seen for a course?

Tags: soft-question, teaching

It seems like every math course has something unique in how things are graded.

1) What are some interesting grading systems you have seen/used?  (include curving types, etc.)

2) What are some pros and cons to this particular system?

3) Would you use it again if you have used it yourself?

One system for grading a final exam that I recently came across was [this](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~kpurbhoo/co630/pageonefinal.pdf).

Comment: Willie has just opened a meta thread http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/836/gradingcurving-systems/. Please direct all comments about the appropriateness of this question there. 

Comment: I voted to close because it is not a research question. In general I think that all curving methods amount to "inverse cheating".

Comment: c.f. http://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2010/08/06/creative-grading-schemes/

Comment: http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~kpurbhoo/co630/pageonefinal.pdf


Comment: For the record, I have yet to see students do well on an intricate grading system like the one the OP linked to. I understand the drive to reward complete solvers over point gleaners, but devise an overly sophisticated systems and students won't act naturally because they don't see clearly where their best strategy lies.

Answer (score 1):

I recall $10\sqrt x$ at the Hebrew University.